# Не происходит расчет матриц определенного типа

Tags: c++, матрицы, вывод, численные-методы

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j, n, m;
//создаем массив
    cout << "vvedite chislo yravneni: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "vvedite chislo neizvestnih: ";
    cin >> m;
    m += 1;
    float** matrix = new float* [n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new float[m];

//инициализируем

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << "Элемент" << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";

            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }

//выводим массив
    cout << "matrix: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

//Метод Гаусса
//Прямой ход, приведение к верхнетреугольному виду
    float tmp, xx[m];
    int k;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = matrix[i][i];
        for (j = n; j >= i; j--)
            matrix[i][j] /= tmp;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            tmp = matrix[j][i];
            for (k = n; k >= i; k--)
                matrix[j][k] -= tmp * matrix[i][k];
        }
    }
/*Обратный ход*/
    xx[n - 1] = matrix[n - 1][n];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        xx[i] = matrix[i][n];
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) xx[i] -= matrix[i][j] * xx[j];
    }

//Выводим решение
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << xx[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    delete[] matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]На первом скриншоте показана работа программы с пробными данными. Решение есть.

[image]
На втором скриншоте показана работа с рабочими данными. Решения нет.

В первом случае расчет проходит без ошибок, а во втором случае не выводится ответ. Код компилируется без ошибок.
В чем кроется суть проблемы я понять не могу.

> 1   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
>   1   1   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
>   0   1   1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
>   0   0   4   -4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
>   0   0   0   16  -57.07 16   0    0    0    0    0
>   0   0   0    0   16  -57.07 16   0    0    0    0
>   0   0   0    0    0    16 -57.07 16   0    0    0
>   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    4   -4    0    0
>   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0
>   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
>   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
>
> 1.8e11
>     8.1e21
>     5.5e32
>     0
>     0
>     0 
>     0
>     0
>     3.7e-11
>     4.7e-22
>     7.2e-33

Comment: Во-первых, хорошо в вопросе написать, что должен делать код. Во-вторых, нужны входные и выходные данные в текстовом виде. Входные - чтобы не перепечатывать их руками, выходные - чтобы читать было удобно. В-третьих, хорошо бы исправить форматирование кода. (Под вопросом есть кнопка [edit].)

Comment: Не пробовали искать в дебаггере, на каком моменте появляется первый `nan`? Может у вас где-то переполнение происходит (тогда можно попробовать взять `double` или `long double` вместо `float`), или деление на ноль?

Comment: Выходных данных нет, их нужно найти.

Comment: Я про вывод программы.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше "приведение к верхнетреугольному виду" ничего к верхнетреугольному виду не приводит, в чем вы можете легко убедиться, распечатав содержимое вашей матрицы после этого "приведения" (почему у вас это не сделано?).

Как только на диагонали появляется `0`, ваш код начинает все делить на `0` c соответствующими последствиями. В алгоритме Гаусса в качестве очередной строки всегда выбирается строка с ненулевым элементом на диагонали. Где у вас в коде выбор такой строки?

Отдельно не понятно, зачем вообще вводилось значение `m`, если в дальнейшем идет работа с матрицей `n x n+1`.

Также, в языке С++ не допускается объявление массивов неконстантного размера. Ваше `float tmp, xx[m];` - это не С++. И при чем здесь вообще `m`, если с `xx` вы в дальнейшем работаете, как с массивом размера `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали матрицу  `matrix`  размера `n * m`, однако везде вы манипулируете элементом матрицы `matrix[i][n]`. Если  `n < m`, то все нормально, если не учитывать факт, что возможно вы не тот результат хотели получать. `Но если n >= m ваш результат неопределен.`
P.S. я не разобрался что вы все таки пытаетесь делать, но  кажется вы по 3 раза  присваиваете элементам массива  значение. Не думаю, что  ваша программа имеет нормальную логику...